# Require help designing VFC (voltage to frequency converter) circuit

Tags: analog, vf-fv-converter

I need to use a VFC (voltage to frequency converter) circuit that operates with bipolar voltage (-10 V to +10 V) and with a bias (i.e. when the input is within +/-2.5 mV, the VFC shall not produce any output).

I was looking into commercially-available VFC such as VFC32 and so-on. Can this requirement be met? Alternatively, can anybody suggest if VFC can be designed from first principles? Linearity should be at least 0.1% for 0-100 kHz range.

Comment: Sounds feasible to meet those requirements.

Comment: And what is 0.1% of zero likely to mean in real terms? Be realistic - if you expect 0 Hz you will be looking for a miracle.

Comment: I do not expect 0 hz, but I would like to inhibit VFC when input is in the range +/- 2.5mV